# What is the function to get the system date and current date in Dynamics AX?

Tags: x++, axapta

What are the function calls to get the System Date and Current Date using X++ in Microsoft Dynamics AX?

Answer (score 13):

Use the static methods within class [DateTimeUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc619601%28v=ax.50%29):

- [getSystemDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc556323%28v=ax.50%29)
- [utcNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc600997%28v=ax.50%29)

Both return UTC date and times, but will be converted to local time on display.

See [Best Practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa605545%28v=ax.50%29).

Answer (score 7):

systemDateGet() and Today()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa672952.aspx

Answer (score 7):

In Dynamics Ax < 2009

Current Date:

```
Today()
```

> The system date provided by the today function should be used only where the actual machine date is needed.

System Date:

```
SystemDateGet()
```

> Most application logic should use the system function systemDateGet, which holds the logic date of the system.

Comment: `SystemDateGet` is deprecated, use the methods from `DateTimeUtil` instead.

Answer (score 2):

SystemDateGet() is the command to get current date in a display method.

today() method, which might return a different date (it
returns the machine date, not the date from Dynamics AX).